# SDO_GEOMETRY error 13348 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>], ora-13348

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

I have a query, which return error 13348 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>]

```
select sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context (SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 32638, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1, 123,2003,1),
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(503155.9729, 4545931.3636, 503141.2136, 4545929.3680, 503120.7778, 4545890.0976, 503120.5720, 4545869.2721, 
503120.5720, 4545846.1102, 503115.0572, 4545828.4628, 503107.3365, 4545820.7423, 503105.1307, 4545799.7861, 503085.2776, 4545788.7565, 
503066.5272, 4545774.4181, 503063.7454, 4545752.8579, 503053.2918, 4545740.2265, 503051.0860, 4545718.1675, 503021.3061, 4545643.1667,
 503002.5557, 4545606.7692, 502984.1996, 4545579.2346, 502958.4378, 4545545.0038, 502957.3349, 4545521.8417, 502950.7171, 4545493.1648,
 502944.8510, 4545482.3126, 502946.1332, 4545483.6864, 502966.1585, 4545500.6307, 503002.0277, 4545530.9815, 503031.8558, 4545572.0962,
 503040.7238, 4545563.2283, 503045.0232, 4545524.5323, 503060.0716, 4545494.4353, 503064.3714, 4545434.2415, 503072.9704, 4545346.1006,
 503077.2699, 4545309.5543, 503083.7193, 4545294.5056, 503107.6265, 4545285.9675, 503105.9029, 4545295.7362, 503097.0790, 4545351.9868, 
503095.9761, 4545377.3547, 503105.9029, 4545410.4434, 503109.2116, 4545450.1496, 503109.2116, 4545477.7236, 503108.1086, 4545527.3564, 
503107.0057, 4545546.1067, 503095.9761, 4545559.3421, 503088.2555, 4545576.9894, 503102.5938, 4545579.1952, 503104.7997, 4545606.7692, 
503088.2555, 4545628.8282, 503080.5348, 4545648.6813, 503079.4317, 4545671.8434, 503080.5348, 4545708.2408, 503091.5643, 4545740.2265, 
503102.5938, 4545771.1093, 503122.4471000010, 4545785.4476, 503152.2268, 4545801.9919, 503162.1534, 4545829.5659, 503165.4623, 4545859.3456,
 503167.6682, 4545885.8165, 503177.5947, 4545881.4047, 503204.0656, 4545876.9928, 503228.3306, 4545873.6840, 503243.7720, 4545873.6840,
 503259.2134, 4545885.8165, 503276.8605, 4545901.2578, 503288.2421, 4545903.2663, 503298.8938, 4545935.9514, 503272.4488, 4545936.5523,
 503254.8015, 4545925.5229, 503231.6395, 4545912.2874, 503218.7349, 4545921.1109, 503207.7054, 4545929.9346, 503196.6759, 4545938.7583, 
503175.7196, 4545945.3760, 503166.8961, 4545944.2730, 503155.9729, 4545931.3636,

494122.3421, 4546309.1762, 494141.8681, 4546318.6243, 494152.5760, 4546337.5203, 494150.0564, 
4546361.4553, 494138.7187, 4546380.9813, 494124.5329, 4546393.4604, 494124.3262, 4546393.7363, 494111.6344, 4546386.7131, 
494083.5899, 4546353.5178, 494075.7316, 4546341.9923, 494071.1720, 4546333.6315, 494084.1080, 4546338.4824, 494095.4270, 
4546338.4824, 494106.7460, 4546323.9296, 494109.3666, 4546315.5439, 494115.4135, 4546311.6956, 494122.3421, 4546309.1762
)), 0.05) from dual;
```

There are two polygons, when I select only one its working and returned true,
there are problem `SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY`, I don't now how to write correctly
plese help me, and explain how to add a third, fourth ... n polygons

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in your geometry:

1. The offset to the second ring (2003) it incorrect.It should 145, not 123
2. The second ring is not an inner ring. It should be a 1003
3. The sdo_gtype should be a 2007 for a multi polygon (not 2003).

Like this:

```
select sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context (
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2007, 32638, null, 
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1, 145,1003,1),
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(
      503155.9729, 4545931.3636, 503141.2136, 4545929.3680, 503120.7778, 4545890.0976, 503120.5720, 4545869.2721, 503120.5720, 4545846.1102, 
      503115.0572, 4545828.4628, 503107.3365, 4545820.7423, 503105.1307, 4545799.7861, 503085.2776, 4545788.7565, 503066.5272, 4545774.4181, 
      503063.7454, 4545752.8579, 503053.2918, 4545740.2265, 503051.0860, 4545718.1675, 503021.3061, 4545643.1667, 503002.5557, 4545606.7692, 
      502984.1996, 4545579.2346, 502958.4378, 4545545.0038, 502957.3349, 4545521.8417, 502950.7171, 4545493.1648, 502944.8510, 4545482.3126, 
      502946.1332, 4545483.6864, 502966.1585, 4545500.6307, 503002.0277, 4545530.9815, 503031.8558, 4545572.0962, 503040.7238, 4545563.2283, 
      503045.0232, 4545524.5323, 503060.0716, 4545494.4353, 503064.3714, 4545434.2415, 503072.9704, 4545346.1006, 503077.2699, 4545309.5543, 
      503083.7193, 4545294.5056, 503107.6265, 4545285.9675, 503105.9029, 4545295.7362, 503097.0790, 4545351.9868, 503095.9761, 4545377.3547, 
      503105.9029, 4545410.4434, 503109.2116, 4545450.1496, 503109.2116, 4545477.7236, 503108.1086, 4545527.3564, 503107.0057, 4545546.1067, 
      503095.9761, 4545559.3421, 503088.2555, 4545576.9894, 503102.5938, 4545579.1952, 503104.7997, 4545606.7692, 503088.2555, 4545628.8282, 
      503080.5348, 4545648.6813, 503079.4317, 4545671.8434, 503080.5348, 4545708.2408, 503091.5643, 4545740.2265, 503102.5938, 4545771.1093, 
      503122.4471, 4545785.4476, 503152.2268, 4545801.9919, 503162.1534, 4545829.5659, 503165.4623, 4545859.3456, 503167.6682, 4545885.8165, 
      503177.5947, 4545881.4047, 503204.0656, 4545876.9928, 503228.3306, 4545873.6840, 503243.7720, 4545873.6840, 503259.2134, 4545885.8165, 
      503276.8605, 4545901.2578, 503288.2421, 4545903.2663, 503298.8938, 4545935.9514, 503272.4488, 4545936.5523, 503254.8015, 4545925.5229, 
      503231.6395, 4545912.2874, 503218.7349, 4545921.1109, 503207.7054, 4545929.9346, 503196.6759, 4545938.7583, 503175.7196, 4545945.3760, 
      503166.8961, 4545944.2730, 503155.9729, 4545931.3636, 
      494122.3421, 4546309.1762, 494141.8681, 4546318.6243, 494152.5760, 4546337.5203, 494150.0564, 
      4546361.4553, 494138.7187, 4546380.9813, 494124.5329, 4546393.4604, 494124.3262, 4546393.7363, 494111.6344, 4546386.7131, 
      494083.5899, 4546353.5178, 494075.7316, 4546341.9923, 494071.1720, 4546333.6315, 494084.1080, 4546338.4824, 494095.4270, 
      4546338.4824, 494106.7460, 4546323.9296, 494109.3666, 4546315.5439, 494115.4135, 4546311.6956, 494122.3421, 4546309.1762
    )
  ), 
  0.05
) from dual;
```

Not sure what you mean by "how to add a third, fourth ... n polygons". Do you mean you need to build a multi-polygon object with a large number of elements ?

Just to be clear if your goal is to populate a table with many objects (for example many land parcels), then you insert one row (= one sdo_geometry) per object. You do not put them all in a single sdo_geometry object.

Can you explain what it is that you want to achieve ?

Comment: How will 145 be for the third and for the fourth polygons

Comment: 145 is the offset into the ordinates array where the second element begins. Use the same technique if you want to add more. You really need to first read and understand the developer's guide for Oracle Spatial.

Comment: Where is the data for your polygons coming from ? You are not really expected to construct geometries entirely manually. The geometries are typically loaded from files or captured using a GIS tool

Comment: If you want to construct a multi-polygon from a set of polygons coming from a table, then look at the SDO_AGGR_UNION() construct.